Problem with npm run dev missing script issues?
I am trying to use npm to run my application. I'm getting the error below:
npm run dev
npm error Missing script: "dev"
npm error
npm error To see a list of scripts, run:
npm error   npm run
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Fatiih\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-17T12_19_10_496Z-debug-0.log

Below is my package.json file:
{
    "name": "pay",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "dev": "nodemon index.js",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "description": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "express": "^4.21.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "passport": "^0.7.0",
        "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
        "passport-oauth2": "^1.8.0",
        "pg": "^8.13.0",
        "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
        "sequelize": "^6.37.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
    }
}

Because of this error, my localhost cannot run. How can I fix it?

What happens when you run npm run?

Nothing happen...

You said npm run dev deosn't work. and in dev you have written nodemon index.js.
Check if nodemon is installed properly: npm list nodemon and if it doesn't exist,
install nodemon locally: npm i --save-dev nodemon or globally npm i -g nodemon
If it doesn't work, try cleaning the cache and run nodemon directly:
npm cache clean --force and npx nodemon index.js.
If it still doesn't work,
Uninstall nodemon: npm uninstall -g nodemon and npm uninstall nodemon.
And try installing again.
If it still doesn't work,
Go to: C:\Users\Fatiih\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-10-17T12_19_10_496Z-debug-0.log and update the question with whatever is there and we can help you more effectively.
Hope it helps.

Still not working

@FatihFevzi how is it "not working"? please may you make sure to explain what is happening.

@FatihFevzi can you recheck the path of your project in your terminal? If its correct, then, remove node_modules folder and reinstall packages by npm install.

Sorry, i am new in this forum how to edit post because i have new error because my package.json file was not top level in App folder it was in App/BackEnd/package,json when i move to App/package.json now i have new error

@FatihFevzi it's ok. You can see the Edit below your question, above the answer section. More specifically, below tags.

@FatihFevzi I think your error might be due to wrong path. Meaning, your project is in another directory and in your terminal you are in another directory. Please check if your path in terminal is where your project folder is.

Yes it's okay now but i have this error: C:\Users\Fatiih\Desktop\BulgPay\BackEnd\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:85
if (!options.authorizationURL) { throw new TypeError('OAuth2Strategy requires a authorizationURL option'); }

@FatihFevzi that's a completely different error which needs a new question

@FatihFevzi if it helped, can you please mark the answer as accepted. And if there is new error, you can ask a new question.
